# Binding a model property directly to a computed property of another model in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm just starting to create a small project with [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/).

Due to structural reasons, I'd like to decompose my model in several sub models like so:

```
var myCtrl = function ($scope) {

    $scope.mainModel = [
        {modelTitle:'learn angular', sum:0},
        {modelTitel:'build an angular app', sum:0}
    ];

    $scope.subModel1 = [
        {item:'learn angular', value:2},
        {item:'build an angular app', value:2}
    ];

    $scope.subModel2 = [
        {item:'learn angular', value:5},
        {item:'build an angular app', value:5}
    ];

}
```

Suppose, that the outcome of `subModel1` and `subModel2` is essential a sum of their item-values.

Thus, the sum of `subModel1` is 4 and the sum of `subModel2` is 10.

**How do I bind programmatically `mainModel[0].sum` to the sum of `subModel1` and likewise for subModel2?**

*Update:* Just found [AngularJS Fundamentals in 60-ish Minutes](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/04/12/video-tutorial-angularjs-fundamentals-in-60-ish-minutes.aspx?goback=.gde_4896676_member_232548482) by [Dan Wahlin](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/default.aspx). A beautiful introduction, which focusses on core concepts.

Comment: You can set a $watch function to watch those values, and when they change, you update mainModel.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you only need the value in your view, you can define a function on $scope:

```
$scope.mainSum = function() {
    return $scope.subModel1[0].value + $scope.subModel2[0].value;
}
```

and then use it in your view:

```
<div>main sum = {{mainSum()}}</div>
```

If you need `mainModel` to be updated, do what @Tim already suggested in a comment -- use [$watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch)es in your controller:

```
$scope.$watch('subModel1[0].value', function(value) {
    $scope.mainSum[0].sum = value + $scope.subModel2[0].value;
});
$scope.$watch('subModel2[0].value', function(value) {
    $scope.mainSum[0].sum = $scope.subModel1[0].value + value;
});
```

Or you can watch the sum:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return $scope.subModel1[0].value + $scope.subModel2[0].value;
 }, function(value) {
    $scope.mainSum[0].sum = value;
});
```

Comment: The case using of using the computed value in a view was already straightforward for me. Actually, I wasn't aware of watchers yet. Thx!